# PHP out of memory, but why?

Tags: php, memory, gd

I have the following line of code, at the start of a function:

```
$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
```

the `$name` contains the full server path to the non-publically accessible folder that contains the image, which is a 4.4MB JPG.

Normally when this problem has occurred, PHP needs more memory than is allocated to open the compressed image, and issuing a `ini_set` command to raise the member to 128MB solves the problem. However, in this case, it does not. I've tried raising to 256, 512 and 1024MB and still it comes back with an error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17152 bytes) in /imgprocess.php on line 83.

I've even tried using the (contraband!) -1 to allow unlimited memory, just to see if something was causing it to go sky high, but still no go.

I've tried a different image file incase it was a bad JPG, still no go.

How can this be solved?

EDIT: I should add that PHP isn't in Safe Mode

Comment: Out of interest, what size is the image (the image *dimensions*, which will have a much better relation to the uncompressed in-memory size than the size of the lossily-compressed JPEG.)

Comment: @Matt: Its 4288x2848 at 72dpi - Photoshop reports it as 34.9MB

Comment: `Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes` something is wrong there. How and where are you setting the memory limit?

Comment: The normal memory limit, set in PHP (and shown on phpinfo) is 32M.  I've tried with the ini_set as the line directly before the imagecreatefromjpeg line. and still no go.  Could there be a setting in PHP which prevents the ini_set from being actioned?

Comment: the image needs about 50M memory to get created. (height*width*4). It is possible to prevent changing the memory limit when php is compiled. usually it is allowed with --enable-memory-limit but I guess some hosting providers might disable it

Comment: @Bastian: Thanks for that.  As i type, the ini_set on the memory is set at 256MB - way higher than it should need, but its still giving the same error.  I've done image resizing on this host in the past and ini_set has always worked. I'm sure its something im missing, but just not sure what!

Comment: I've just confirmed with ini_get that after using ini_set the memory is set to 256MB.  Thats checked just before the line thats causing the error.  So ini_set is working correctly

Comment: I should have added on the past comment that the error is still there!

Comment: Well I did not solve the query, of why the system is continually running out of memory, but I have confirmed that using Imagemagick solved the problem and allowed the thumbnail to be created with ease.

Thanks to all for your help - if anyone has any further thoughts, do let me know, as I would like to solve this one!

Comment: Your memory limit setting is clearly not being applied. 262144 bytes is 262 kilobytes.

Comment: @Pekka - Yes that was my thought, but when you use ini_set at the start of the script, and then use ini_get just above the line thats causing the error - it shows that the memory limit is set to 256MB - phpinfo shows the default setting as 32MB, so it is being applied.

Comment: Can you show what value you give to `ini_set()` and what `ini_get()` returns?

Comment: In the code I have ini_set('memory_limit', '256MB').  The when I then do echo 'Memory Limit: ' . ini_get('memory_limit'); later in the script, the screen shows Memory Limit: 256MB.  Take the ini_set away and the screen shows Memory Limit: 32MB

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256m');
```

Please read [faq.using.shorthandbytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes)

Using "MB" is a wrong shorthand notation. ini_get() doesn't return normalized values most often it returns what it was set to.